# Error: Could not resolve <s:SWFLoader> to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flexmojos

I'm currently converting Flex project currently build by Ant to a project built by Maven.

I receive the following error:

```
Could not resolve <s:SWFLoader> to a component implementation.
```

In

```
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
```

Seems that there is unresolved dependency. These are my dependencies in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.19786</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.19786</version>
        <type>swc</type>
    </dependency>
```

What I must add in the pom.xml file?

EDIT: Following does not seems to work, the error stays the same

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0.19786</version>
    <type>swc</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mx:SWFLoader` with `mx` namespace.